# Deleting rows in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c

I have a tableview in UIViewController and I want to delete a row of the tableview and also update a sqlite db. While at the edge of the cell deleted my apps get terminated, randomly.

Here is the code in question:

```
NSMutableArray * FeedArr;
NSString *query,*sid;
sid=[[FeedArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"feedId"];
DB *dbobj=[[DB alloc]init];
query=@"DELETE FROM FEED_MASTER WHERE feedId=?";
[dbobj deleteFromDatabase:sid Query:query];

query=@"DELETE FROM ITEMS_MASTER WHERE feedId=?";
[dbobj deleteFromDatabase:sid Query:query];

[FeedArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Can any help me?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Show us the code you wrote to delete the row and maybe we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

NSMutableArray * FeedArr;
NSString *query,*sid;
            sid=[[FeedArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"feedId"];
            DB *dbobj=[[DB alloc]init];
            query=@"DELETE FROM FEED_MASTER WHERE feedId=?";
            [dbobj deleteFromDatabase:sid Query:query];

```
        query=@"DELETE FROM ITEMS_MASTER WHERE feedId=?";
        [dbobj deleteFromDatabase:sid Query:query];

        [FeedArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```